# Change custom adapter contents

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to put data that i get from a webservice into a custom adapter to show in my grid, the problem is that the download takes some time to finish in an Async call so when i try to set the adapter the Array of data(movies in this case) is null.

Heres my activity:

```
package com.movieposter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String API = "***";
    private Movie[] movies;
    private GridView grid;
    private ImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        getMovies();
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, movies);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void getMovies(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=**")
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                String json = response.body().string();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("teste", response.body().string());
                        movies = parseMovie(json);



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Movie[] parseMovie(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonMovie = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray data = jsonMovie.getJSONArray("results");
        Movie[] movies = new Movie[data.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++ ){
            JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setOverview(jsonObject.getString("overview"));
            movie.setRating(jsonObject.getDouble("vote_average"));
            movie.setReleaseDate(jsonObject.getString("release_date"));
            movie.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
            movie.setThumbnail("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + jsonObject.getString("poster_path"));
            movies[i] = movie;
        }
        return movies;
    }



}
```

And my adapter

```
package com.movieposter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    Movie[] movies;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Movie[] movies) {
        mContext = c;
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return movies.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return movies[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(movies[position].getThumbnail()).into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

I tried to set the adapter inside the onResponse method but that did not work, whats the best approach for loading data from webservices into your apater if you dont know when the data will finish? Is it possible to set a empty adapter and then replace the contents once the data is ready? is so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set a empty adapter and then replace the contents once the data is ready? is so, how?

You answered your question yourself. Yes it is possible. First of all you should consider using a `List<Movie>` instead of an array `Movie[]` because you might not know the number of movies you will get.

There are two approaches to this

1. You can initialize the adaptor with an empty `List<Movies> movies` and just show the list and in the onResponse you append to the `List<Movies> movies` the new data that you get and then all `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adaptor.
2. If you only need to call the service once you can initially keep the `ListView` hidden and in the `onResponse` you can initialize the `adaptor` with the data, attach it to the adaptor and make the list the visible. Until then you can show a loading spinner or something.

For a quick test just try this inside the `onResponse`:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    try {
        Log.i("teste", response.body().string());
        movies = parseMovie(json);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //add this

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, i just had to include a runOnUi call because the adapter updates the contents of the UI, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a List instead of an array to store the Objects. Because the data structure should be dynamic (You never know how many movies are there..).

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();// First keep this empty.
```

Then,

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    try {
        Log.i("teste", response.body().string());
        movies.clear();// Do not re assign 
        movies.addAll(parseMovie(json)); // just clear and add new movies
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //add this

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```